# Mongoose Reverse Lookup in Recursive Association

Tags: recursion, mongoose, associations, schema

I am trying to implement users following users and I have

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  following: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }]
});

var User = mongoose.model('User',UserSchema);
```

So now, as a user I want get a list of my followers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run a complex query to get your followers, however it's much easier to store followers in the document too:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  followers: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }],
  following: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }],
});
```

This requires a bit more work on updates, however it pays off on reads (which happen more often than updates).